# Thumbnail size keeps resetting automatically

Tags: images, thumbnails

Thumbnail size on my website is controlled by a setting in the theme. I set them - width 550 and height 339. When I publish a new post, the thumbnail size changes automatically.

Now I set the same size 550/339 in WordPress Media Settings. But the size still keeps resetting.

When I save the thumbnail size in the theme they are restored.

Please help me to fix the issue, I will always be grateful.

[image: Thumbnail size]

Note - Any plugin is not used for generating thumbnails. The website is https://www.howto-connect.com/, Please help out.

1. Before reset -

```
<img width="550" height="339" alt="Windows 11 Build 22000.1279 KB5019157" decoding="async" loading="lazy" data-src="https://www.howto-connect.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Windows-11-Build-22000.1279-KB5019157.codzoc-550x339.png" class="mag-thumbnail wp-post-image ls-is-cached lazyloaded" src="https://www.howto-connect.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Windows-11-Build-22000.1279-KB5019157.codzoc-550x339.png">
```

and 2. after reset -

```
<img width="200" height="148" alt="Windows 11 Build 22000.1279 KB5019157" decoding="async" loading="lazy" data-src="https://www.howto-connect.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Windows-11-Build-22000.1279-KB5019157.codzoc-200x148.png" class="mag-thumbnail wp-post-image lazyloaded" src="https://www.howto-connect.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Windows-11-Build-22000.1279-KB5019157.codzoc-200x148.png">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I save the thumbnail size in the theme"? It sounds like your theme is messing with this setting. If that's the case you will need to ask the theme author for assistance.

Comment: Thanks Jacob for responding, Theme Settings include Blog thumb width
and height. When the thumbnail size is reset I have to click on "Save change"s to bring the chosen size back.  You can see https://prnt.sc/R7ZouZiQEwew. I am thinking if I can bypass this setting through some functions or PHP.

Comment: Theme maker is not helping and telling me that I have tweaked the original codes for customizations in the website which is obvious thing.

Comment: I am assuming that this is caching or lazyload problem

Comment: Solved the problem. This was due to conflict between 2 plugins Smush and lightspeed cache. On both, lazyloading was enabled. After disabling lazyload on lightspeed cache the thumbnails are working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the support anyway.